# Node Request: Get certain class/id

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, node-request

I am using the Node module `Request`. I have also used `node-fetch` in the past but `request` seems better. I want to be able to log something with a certain ID/Class/Span, you name it. This is my current code which logs the whole body.

```
const request = require('request');

request("https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember", (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    console.log(body)
});
```

I want to log the contents of any `Property` the user gives, let's say they give `bannable` I want to log the contents of `div#doc-for-bannable.class-prop.class-item` but I'm not sure how to do this.

Edit:

I tried using Cheerio as suggested but it is not giving me any sort of response, just a blank space in my console.The code I tried was:

```
request("https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember", (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    const $ = cheerio.load(body);

    const g = $('docs-page'); // this doesn't work either, after trying '#doc-for-bannable`

    const gText = g.text();

    console.log(gText)
});
```

Comment: Take a look at `cheerio`. It is exactly what you need. https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Comment: @KrishnaKalubandi I edited my original post and explained the issue I've ran into now.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying request page builds the DOM after requesting data from backend using XHR/ajax requests.

So when you use 'request', the page is loaded without XHR being fired

However, if you closely look at the Network tab, you will come across
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/docs/stable.json

This has the data that you are looking for.
You can use the nodejs 'request' for this url and consume the json

Comment: That's amazing thank you! I can work with JSON. However there is one problem, if you collapse them all and only open the `classes` then it returns a list of 70 classes only numbered (not by their actual name, for example: `GuildMember`) which is number 33, is there anyway instead of saying `classes[33].methods[16].name` to say `classes[GuildMember]` or something of sorts?

Comment: you will need to map your array to your preferred object pattern (basic JS)